# wordpress get_categories function not working

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am trying to retrieve categories from the `category` taxonomy of the `custom post` type
By the below codes :

```
$categories = get_categories(array(
        'type'        => 'ad_listing',
        'child_of'    => 0,
        'parent'      => '',
        'orderby'     => 'name',
        'order'       => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'  => 1,
        'hierarchical'=> 1,
        'exclude'     => '',
        'include'     => '',
        'number'      => '',
        'taxonomy'    => 'ad_cat',
        'pad_counts'  => false 
    ));
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($categories);
    echo"</pre>";
```

But it is not showing nothing in category though there are 3 categories.
i think i am doing something wrong :(

Comment: Do you have any posts in those categories? `hide_empty` isn't showing categories without posts attached to them.

Answer (score 4):

It will work,

```
  $cat_args = array(
                      'parent'  => 0,
                      'hide_empty' => 0,
                      'order'    => 'ASC',
                   );
    $categories = get_categories($cat_args);
    foreach($categories as $category){
       echo get_cat_name($category->term_id); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check any post assing in any category or not.If any post not assing any category then no category show.

If you want to show all category without post assign to category. Change hide_empty=>false See below code

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories( array(
            'type'        => 'post',
            'child_of'    => 0,
            'parent'      => '',
            'orderby'     => 'name',
            'order'       => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty'  => false,
            'hierarchical'=> 1,
            'exclude'     => '',
            'include'     => '',
            'number'      => '',
            'taxonomy'    => 'category',
            'pad_counts'  => false 
        ) );
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($categories);
    echo"</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Hello,I had a mistake on my question.It would be custom post type.See the question again pls

Comment: Your code working for me. If you fetch all category without  post  attach to category, change 'hide_empty'  => false,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code work for me.

```
global $wpdb;
$all_cats = array();
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'field' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false
);
$all_cats = get_categories($args);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($all_cats);
```

Comment: Hello,I had a mistake on my question.It would be custom post type.See the question again pls

Answer (score 0):

Use  `<?php get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator ) ?>` get_categories might be for `post_type='post'`

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies